# Rails, link_to helper with an URL as a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, url-helper

I want to generate the next html link:

```
<a href="http://url.com">http://url.com</a>
```

To reproduce it using the `link_to` helper I have to write:

```
<%= link_to "http://url.com", "http://url.com" %>
```

What doesn't look DRY at all, I was expecting this to work:

```
<%= link_to "http://url.com" %>
```

But the above code generate a link targeting the actual `request.url`, not the one I'm sending in the param.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing anything --- the normal case is for the URL and the text that shows to the user to be different.

If you'd like, you could create a helper like

```
def link_to_href(link, args={})
  link_to link, link, args
end
```

then, when you use it,

```
<%= link_to_href "http://url.com" %>
```

Will output

```
<a href="http://url.com">http://url.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L231) of `link_to` you will see that [at line 248](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L248) the `a` tag label is build with `name || url`.

That's why you have this behaviour and there is noway to do it like you're expecting.